# Algorithm - Choose next query based on previous one

Tags: algorithm

Looking for a Algorithm which helps in selecting Next question based on the previous question answer. Ex : If first question is 
1. Do you own a smart phone ?
If yes
2. What type of sensors it has ?

If No
2. Which smart phone would you like to buy ?

The branching of these questions should be based on the last question and it answer. 
  What are the techniques can be followed to derive this. Any general purpose Algorithm is available for the same.

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165519/where-should-i-post-questions-about-algorithms-stack-overflow-or-programmers-se

Comment: This is nothing with algorithm. You keep a set of (Question, Answer, NextQuestion) s.t. whenever an answer is received, check out the next question, and continue.

Comment: @KenCheung Yes the format of (Q, A, NQ) is fine. This way of representing the question & answers can be something like node - path - node in graph database. Hope an NEO4J implementation might be good for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decide if the question should be asked or not. This is one way. I haven't provided the QuestionContext, it's your job to decide how to store the answers and decide if the question is available based on that.

I was tempted to go with the `next()` question method, but sometimes you need a little more context(i.e. if you own a smartphone & smartphone is from Apple, ask what version of iOS is running).

Hope this helps!

```
interface Question {
  public boolean isAvailable(QuestionContext ctx);
  public void ask();
  // ... rest of the methods
}

public class Questionnaire implements QuestionContext {
  private Question[] qs;

  // constructors, getters, etc.

  public void ask() {
     for (Question q : qs) {
       if (q.isAvailable(this)) {
         q.ask();
       }
     }
  }
}
```

p.s. If you need something more complex, there are some flow frameworks available for various tasks, but you'll have to get the idea and come up with something that works for your needs. One example is `Spring WebFlow` that decides, in a wizard-like set of pages context, which page is next.

Comment: In general at code level this looks to be fine, but answer need to be consider for next question. As you pointed out, it is required to build a Chain of questions branching based on answers. Will checkout Spring WebFlow will help on this.